# Save/Update an array with Mongoose doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm a newbie with Mongoose... and I'm not able to save/update an array.

When I create the user who login with his email, I use something like this:

```
User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {

var newUser = new User(); 
var name = req.body.name;

newUser.local.name    = name;
newUser.local.array = [1, 2];

newUser.save(function(err) {
 if (err)
    throw err;
    return done(null, newUser);
 });
 });
```

It works fine, the user is saved !

But when I update the user:

```
app.post('/change', function(req, res) {

var newUser = new User(); 
newUser.isNew = false;

newUser._id    = req.user._id;
var newname = req.body.name; 
newUser.local.array    = [3, 4];

newUser.save(function(err) {
 if (err)
    throw err;
    return done(null, newUser);
 });
 });
```

It doesn't work, the console log "VersionError: No matching Document found".
If I comment the line where local.array is invloved in the update, it works fine, the user is updated.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You need to get the existing user document to update using `findOne` instead of calling `new User()` again. Otherwise, how would it know which document you're updating?

Comment: Your first code snippet is wrong. `User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {`. You should either use the returned `user` object, or create a new one if one doesn't exist like you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Calling save on a mongoose object will only make a modification to an existing database entry if that mongoose object was obtained via `find` or `findOne`. The [mongoose findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) can do this in one step.

Or you could just use Mongo's standard method of updating existing documents. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to update the document ! Cheers